# How to make a rubik's cube dataframe transformation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a transformation rubik's cube like (see I/O below) :

##### # INPUT :

```
  COLX COLY COLZ
0    A    C  NaN
1    C    B    A
2    C  NaN    B
```

##### # OUTPUT :

```
      COLX     COLY COLZ
0        A  Missing    C
1        A        B    C
2  Missing        B    C
```

Basically, I need to sort the values of each row alphabetically.

Here is the dataframe I'm using :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'COLX': ['A', 'C', 'C'], 'COLY': ['C', 'B', np.nan] , 'COLZ': [np.nan, 'A', 'B']})
```

Is there any propositions ?
Should I use [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) ? If so, how to proceed, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's stack, then pivot:

```
out = (df.stack().reset_index(name='value')
   .assign(col=lambda x: x['value'])
   .pivot(index='level_0', columns='col', values='value')
   .fillna('Missing')
)
out.columns = df.columns
```

Output:

```
            COLX     COLY COLZ
level_0                       
0              A  Missing    C
1              A        B    C
2        Missing        B    C
```

---

Update per request:

```
out = (df.stack().reset_index(name='value')
   .assign(col=lambda x: x['value'])
   .pivot(index='level_0', columns='col', values='value')
)
out[:] = np.where(out.isna(), ['Missing_' + out.columns], out)
out.columns = df.columns
```

Output:

```
              COLX       COLY COLZ
level_0                           
0                A  Missing_B    C
1                A          B    C
2        Missing_A          B    C
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks Quang Hoang.

Comment: I have a last question if you don't mind. What if we want to add a suffix to `Missing` ? Is it possible ? for example, `Missing` in `COLX` will be `Missing A` and  `Missing` in `COLY` will be `Missing B` and so on..

Comment: @Stormy see updated answer.