# Why pandas doesn't offer a rubik's cube built-in transformation?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to achieve this weird transformation :

[image]

The input is made of some random blocks including 6 cells (colored in the image above).

The order is not important in the output !
Here is the dataframe used :

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

dico = {0: ['aa', 'bb', 'ee', nan, 'cc', nan, nan, nan, nan, 'REF A', 'REF B'],
 1: ['dd', 'REF A', 'REF B', nan, nan, nan, nan, 'jj', nan, nan, nan],
 2: ['ff', nan, nan, nan, nan, 'REF A', 'REF B', nan, nan, 'val7', 9393],
 3: [nan, 'val1', 123, 'kk', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'ff', nan],
 4: [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'val2', 4194, 'hh', nan, 'REF A', 'REF B'],
 5: ['REF A', 'REF B', 'REF A', 'REF B', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
 6: [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'REF A', 'REF B', nan, nan, 'val6', 113],
 7: ['val3', 2334, 'val4', 4488, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
 8: [nan, nan, 'gg', nan, nan, 'val5', 773, nan, nan, 'ii', nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dico)
```

Do you have some suggestions guys ?
Thank you so much !

Comment: I would guess a lack of demand is the reason why pandas does not offer such a transformation as a build-in :-) Could you give more details on your use case? This question is also asking about a rubik's cube transformation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73832487. I don't see how your usecase is connected to a rubik's cube, maybe your transform is related?

Comment: Hi @peer, I coudn't think of something other than rubik's cube. You're right, I might be failed to describe the kind of tranformation I'm looking for but hopefully that people here in SO will give us some insights. What kind of your details do you need ?

Comment: I was really surprised to see yet another question about a "rubik's cube transformation", so I was curious about the use case. Knowing it might also help understand why you ended up with this problem. Maybe there is a simpler way for the original problem? What you are trying to achieve reminds me of pooling / filtering / convolutions. Of course those would usually be done on numbers only and using numpy. I am not aware of a good way to solve this in pandas (because the question is not really about rows and columns, but rather searching in a 2d array), but I haven't been using it in a while...

Comment: As an aside, is this from an excel file?

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy, yes.

Comment: I'll give it a go... If you can share the excel file or a sample excel file I could offer another way about it. At any rate, you can use pandas to wrangle this

Comment: Thank you! I uploaded the Excel file here : https://cjoint.com/c/LJpbOTWnL5x. I also posted an answer. Let me know if I'm doing something wrong !

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. If you want a way to do something, ask for it - don't ask why it doesn't appear to be built-in. Either it is (and the question is inappropriate due to a lack of research) or it isn't (and it comes across as a rant, or at best a request to defend a design decision in subjective terms) Neither way makes a good question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your excel file has colours and other metadata that show how the REF and val and numbers are connected. Let's take advantage of that with [xlsx_cells](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/io/#janitor.io.xlsx_cells) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/). Under the hood it uses [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to generate a Pandas DataFrame with all the metadata that we can then use to reshape to the desired form:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
from janitor import xlsx_cells

path = 'Downloads/rubic.xlsx'
df = xlsx_cells(path, include_blank_cells=False, sheetnames=0, fill=True)
target = df.loc[df.fill.str['fgColor'].str['tint'].ne(0), ['value']]
cond = target.value.str.startswith('REF', na=False)
other = np.where(~cond, target.value, np.nan)
# fill the nulls above with the values below
target = target.assign(other = other).bfill()
target = target.loc[target.value != target.other]
index = target.groupby('value').cumcount()
(target
.assign(index = index)
.pivot(index = 'index', columns = 'value', values = 'other')
.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)

  REF A REF B
0  val3  2334
1  val1   123
2  val4  4488
3  val2  4194
4  val5   773
5  val7  9393
6  val6   113
```

**BREAKDOWN:**

- Here we read in the data - it puts every cell into its own row, along with some relevant metadata:

```py
path = 'Downloads/rubic.xlsx'
df = xlsx_cells(path, include_blank_cells=False, sheetnames=0, fill=True)
df.head()

  value internal_value coordinate  row  column data_type  is_date number_format                                               fill
0     0              0         A1    1       1         n    False       General  {'patternType': None, 'fgColor': {'rgb': '0000...
1     1              1         B1    1       2         n    False       General  {'patternType': None, 'fgColor': {'rgb': '0000...
2     2              2         C1    1       3         n    False       General  {'patternType': None, 'fgColor': {'rgb': '0000...
3     3              3         D1    1       4         n    False       General  {'patternType': None, 'fgColor': {'rgb': '0000...
4     4              4         E1    1       5         n    False       General  {'patternType': None, 'fgColor': {'rgb': '0000...
```

We know the rows are connected with some colour; you can access the `fill` column to see the sub keys - internally `fill` is a dictionary per row:

```py
df.fill[0]
{'patternType': None,
 'fgColor': {'rgb': '00000000', 'type': 'rgb', 'tint': 0.0},
 'bgColor': {'rgb': '00000000', 'type': 'rgb', 'tint': 0.0}}
```

The useful metadata available here is the tint - for the relevant rows that are coloured, the tint is not zero - let's use that to filter just for the rows we are interested in:

```py
target = df.loc[df.fill.str['fgColor'].str['tint'].ne(0), ['value']]
target.head()
    value
12  REF A
13   val3
15  REF A
16   val1
17  REF B
```

We also know from the data that after each REF comes either val or a number; we'll use that pattern to reshape accordingly:

```py
cond = target.value.str.startswith('REF', na=False)
other = np.where(~cond, target.value, np.nan)
# fill the nulls above with the values below
target = target.assign(other = other).bfill()
target = target.loc[target.value != target.other]
target.head()

    value other
12  REF A  val3
15  REF A  val1
17  REF B  2334
20  REF B   123
22  REF A  val4
```

All that's left is to pivot - we create a unique column with `groupby.cumcount` before pivoting:

```py
index = target.groupby('value').cumcount()
(target
.assign(index = index)
.pivot(index = 'index', columns = 'value', values = 'other')
.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)

  REF A REF B
0  val3  2334
1  val1   123
2  val4  4488
3  val2  4194
4  val5   773
5  val7  9393
6  val6   113
```

This is specific to the data you shared; for other forms, you might have to do more/less wrangling - and it is dependent on being able to identify the right pattern.

Another possible solution is with numpy; again this is specific to the data shared.

There is a pattern, `REF A` is paired with `val*`, while `REF B` is paired with the numbers. We also know that the numbers are immediately below the `val`. Let's use that pattern to generate the dataframe:

```py
# get booleans for cells that start with `val`
# convert to numpy
# index within numpy space
bools = df.apply(lambda df: df.str.startswith("val")).to_numpy(na_value=False)
bools = bools.astype(np.bool8)
arr = df.to_numpy()
vals = arr[bools]
rows, cols = bools.nonzero()
# we know that the numbers are in the immediate next row
# directly underneath val
# hence the increment when indexing
numbers = arr[rows + 1, cols]
pd.DataFrame({'REF A': vals, 'REF B' : numbers})
  REF A REF B
0  val3  2334
1  val1   123
2  val4  4488
3  val2  4194
4  val5   773
5  val7  9393
6  val6   113
```

Comment: i'll add another solution using numpy - might be helpful for scenarios where it is not an excel file.

Comment: I loved both solutions TBH and `pyjanitor` looks very powerful. It seems to me to as a pandas patch since it offers almost all the crazy data manipulation that `pandas` are not supporting. Thank you so much sammy ;)

Comment: Pyjanitor is just a wrapper around pandas

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution (that obviously may not be the best one) :

First of all, just to make sure that every block has the two values for `REF A` and `REF B` :

```
df.fillna("Missing Value", inplace=True)
```

Then,

###### # --- Masking any value different from the 4 cells block

```
m1 = ~(df[df.columns].isin(['REF A', 'REF B']))
m2 = ~(df[df.columns].isin(['REF A', 'REF B'])).shift(2, axis=1).fillna(False)

out1 = (
        pd.DataFrame(df.mask(m1 & m2)
                       .stack()
                       .reset_index()
                       .groupby("level_1").agg(list)
                       .pop(0).tolist())
          .stack()
       )
#<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

###### # --- Getting rid of any row containing the expected columns names

```
out2 = (
        out1.loc[~out1.str.startswith("REF").fillna(False)]
            .reset_index(level=0)
            .drop(columns="level_0")
            .reset_index(drop=True)
       )
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

###### # --- Making the final dataframe by joining every row with the next one

```
out3 = (
            out2.rename(columns={0: "REF A"})
                .join(out2.shift(-1).rename(columns={0: 'REF B'}))
                .iloc[::2]
                .sort_values(by="REF A") #optionally
                .reset_index(drop=True)
       )
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

**Output :**

```
print(out3)

  REF A REF B
0  val1   123
1  val2  4194
2  val3  2334
3  val4  4488
4  val5   773
5  val6   113
6  val7  9393
```